# Accessing Object Elements via For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

Okay, so I've tired quite a few things. And I'm still boggled, and I know the answer is going to be something ridiculously simple, but I have to ask anyway.

I have a function:

```
Module.load = function(a) {
  require("./modules/"+a+".js");
  Module.loaded.push(a);
  Log("Loaded Module: "+a); 
};
```

And using `Module.load('basic');` loads the basic file. 
Now, I'm defining modules via an object:

```
Modules = { basic:1,queue:0,admin:1,notify:0 }
```

So I wrote this function:

```
for (x in Modules) { if (Modules[x] == 1) Module.load(x); };
```

But it's not working, and for the *life* of me, I can't figure out why.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You don't see the output of `Log()`? Also, you're making `x` a global variable without `var`.

Comment: Let me add the 'var' and see what happens, derp. And yes, I don't see the output of log, and I can't access the loaded files.

Comment: Simply adding 'var' did it. I feel absolutely retarded, but I predicted it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, can someone explain why `var` matters here? Is this something specific to node? (I know Javascript but haven't ever used node.)

Comment: If you're using globals, you might use the `x` global somewhere else in one of the functions that `load()` is calling. It's a good idea to get in the habit of *always* making the variables local.

Comment: @rid, in general yes globals are dangerous, but I don't why in this particular code `x` would be a problem, unless there's something about node that I don't know. In plain old JS in a browser, the for loop would finish running before anything else gets popped off the event loop, so I can't see why `x` would get modified unless `require` or `Log` use a global `x` variable, which would be surprising.

Comment: Oh, I see, `require` immediately executes the file, so that code might also be using a global `x`.

Comment: @Emily, that's true, simply running `a = {a: 1, b: 2}; for (x in a) { console.log(a[x]); }` in node works as expected. So it's likely not something node-related. I suppose the most likely explanation is that one of the OP's functions is somehow doing something related to a global `x` (either the `require`d code, or `Log()`).

Comment: As noted in my other comment, `"use strict"` will alleviate simple "forgot var" declaration issues. :)

Answer (score 4):

The code works:

```
var Module = {}; Module.load = function(a) {
  console.log("Loaded Module: "+a); 
};

var Modules = { basic:1,queue:0,admin:1,notify:0 }

for (var x in Modules) { if (Modules[x] == 1) Module.load(x); };
```

```
Loaded Module: basic
Loaded Module: admin
```

Therefore the problem must be elsewhere. Make sure that:

- you don't have any syntax error
- `Module.loaded` exists and is an array
- `require` is defined as a function and doesn't crash
- `Log` is defined as a function and doesn't crash

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have the 'var'. I just had `for (x...)`

Comment: `"use strict"` should help catch these bugs. With use strict defined, you'll get a nice error like `ReferenceError: x is not defined`